# Mysql relative date subtraction

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, join

I have the following two tables

```
# Event table
id    title         start_date              end_date
----------------------------------------------------------
1      Foo     2013-05-06 20:30:00     2013-05-06 22:45:00
2      Bar     2013-06-03 07:40:00     2013-05-06 10:45:00
3      Demo    2013-05-02 00:22:00     2013-05-06 03:45:00
4      Test    2013-07-09 10:56:00     2013-05-06 13:45:00

# Notification table
id   event_id         mail         time    type     sent
----------------------------------------------------------
1       1       123@example.com     15    minute     0
2       1       234@example.com     01    day        0
3       3       655@example.com     01    week       0
4       4       888@example.com     40    minute     0
5       4       999@example.com     42    minute     1
5       4       987@example.com     30    minute     0
```

Every minute a cron job executes a PHP script to check if a notification should be sent to the email address in the notification table. The time value is the relative time before the start date of the event when the reminder should be sent.

For example when the cron job runs at *2013-05-06 20:15:00* an email should be sent to the email address **123@example.com**. A sent flag should also be considered. If this is set to 0 then all notifications should be sent also if it is lower than the send date. For example when the cron job runs at *2013-07-09 10:26:00* a mail should be sent to **987@example.com** and **888@example.com**.

My question is, how does the query have to look like in mysql to fetch the notifications to meet the requirements from above for the actual (now()) date? I tried with [date_sub](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) but was not really successful. An help is really appreciated.

Comment: hard to say, but a truth. Keeping type in Notification table is an ugly DB design

Comment: What would be a better approach? Your comment was not really helpful!!

Comment: Keeping all types in a lookup table and keeping its reference in notification table could hasten the dynamic calculation of balance time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to this problem, as far as I can tell.  One is converting the different units into time comparisons.  The other is making sure that only one notification goes out.

The first can be handled by a big `case` statement.  The second can be handled by checking for an interval on the time, instead of an inequality:

```
. . .
from event e join
     notification n
     on e.id = n.event_id
where (case when n.type = 'minute'
            then now() - interval n.time minute <= e.start_date and
                 now() + interval 1 minute - interval time minute > e.start_date
            when n.type = 'day'
            then now() - interval n.time day <= e.start_date and
                 now() + interval 1 minute - interval time day > e.start_date
            when n.type = 'week'
            then now() - interval 7*n.time day <= e.start_date and
                 now() + interval 1 minute - interval 7*time day > e.start_date
            when n.type = 'month'
            then now() - interval n.time month <= e.start_date and
                 now() + interval 1 minute - interval time month > e.start_date
       end) > 0 and sent = 0;
```

And, as Tom points out, it would be better to have a sent flag for each notification, rather than depending on the particular time.  Jobs can be delayed for all sorts of reasons.

Comment: Gordon, you have some syntax errors.  You use date_sub a couple times, but also are adding/subtracting intervals.  Plus you have a couple extra end parens.

Comment: Also, wouldn't it be better to use the sent flag rather than use a date range?

Comment: @Tom . . . Thank you for the edits.  As for your second comment, I wholeheartedly agree.  Depending on the particular time frame is likely to be dangerous in most environments.

Comment: The sent falg is there but it is not used in your solution. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: You have to change *now() - interval n.time month* to *now() + interval n.time month* because now needs to be before the start date. It is an addition and no subtraction. Please accept my edit.